# How to use select parent > child with jquery parent() function

Tags: jquery, ajax, parent-child

I need to select the parent div then child of that with a certain class to append data too when i link is clicked. Please let me know if this makes sense. This makes an ajax call and returns data and needs to append the number to the div called 'num' but I can't seem to select it right

```
$('.add_fav').live('click', function(){
        var link = $(this);
        var div = $(this).parent().parent();

        // this is where the problem is
        var num = $(this).parent().$('.favnumholder');

        $.get($(this).attr('href'),{}, function(data){
        var data = data.split(':');
            if(data[0] == 'added'){
                div.addClass("hasclass");
                link.addClass('favorited');
                link.attr('href', 'ajax/add-fav.php?action=rm&fav_type='+data[2]+'&fav_id='+data[1]);
                link.text('Un-fav');
                num.html(data[3]);
            } else if(data[0] == 'removed') {
                div.removeClass("hasclass");
                link.removeClass('favorited');
                link.attr('href', 'ajax/add-fav.php?action=add&fav_type='+data[2]+'&fav_id='+data[1]);
                link.text('Fav');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var num = $(this).parent().find('.favnumholder');
```

or

```
var num = $('.favnumholder', $(this).parent());
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
var num = $('.favnumholder', $(this).parent());
```

This selects favnumholder in the parent element